# Most efficient method in simplifying quotient determinant(Cramer's rule) with binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, determinant

The matrix entries are defined as:

$$ c_{n,i} = \binom{n}{i} \binom{3}{i} i!$$

For $ i , n \in [0,3]$

As a matrix it looks like:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \binom{1}{0} \binom{3}{0} 0! &  \binom{1}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & 0& 0\\ 
\binom{2}{0} \binom{3}{0} 0! &  \binom{2}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & \binom{2}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2!& 0\\
\binom{3}{0} \binom{3}{0} 0! &  \binom{3}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & \binom{3}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2!&  \binom{3}{3} \binom{3}{3} 3! \\ 
\binom{4}{0} \binom{3}{0} 0! &  \binom{4}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & \binom{4}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2!&  \binom{4}{3} \binom{3}{3} 3!\end{bmatrix} = A$$

I have a linear system of the form:

$$ A \begin{bmatrix} q\\w\\e\\r \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d  \end{bmatrix}$$

And, I need to find the quantity '$q$' that is by cramer's rule,

$$ q=  \frac{\begin{vmatrix} a&  \binom{1}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & 0& 0\\ 
b &  \binom{2}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & \binom{2}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2!& 0\\
c &  \binom{3}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & \binom{3}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2!&  \binom{3}{3} \binom{3}{3} 3! \\ 
d &  \binom{4}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & \binom{4}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2!&  \binom{4}{3} \binom{3}{3} 3!\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix} \binom{1}{0} \binom{3}{0} 0! &  \binom{1}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & 0& 0\\ 
\binom{2}{0} \binom{3}{0} 0! &  \binom{2}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & \binom{2}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2!& 0\\
\binom{3}{0} \binom{3}{0} 0! &  \binom{3}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & \binom{3}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2!&  \binom{3}{3} \binom{3}{3} 3! \\ 
\binom{4}{0} \binom{3}{0} 0! &  \binom{4}{1} \binom{3}{1} 1! & \binom{4}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2!&  \binom{4}{3} \binom{3}{3} 3!\end{vmatrix}} $$

Now, we can simplify this to get:

$$ q=  \frac{\begin{vmatrix} a&  \binom{1}{1}  & 0& 0\\ 
b &  \binom{2}{1} & \binom{2}{2} & 0\\
c &  \binom{3}{1} & \binom{3}{2} &  \binom{3}{3}  \\ 
d &  \binom{4}{1} & \binom{4}{2}&  \binom{4}{3} \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix} \binom{1}{0}  &  \binom{1}{1} & 0& 0\\ 
\binom{2}{0} &  \binom{2}{1} & \binom{2}{2} & 0\\
\binom{3}{0}  &  \binom{3}{1}& \binom{3}{2}&  \binom{3}{3}  \\ 
\binom{4}{0}  &  \binom{4}{1} & \binom{4}{2} &  \binom{4}{3}\end{vmatrix}} $$

Progress: Turns out the denominator is always equal one for any size of the matrice, now only need to work out num

Any advice on how to simplify these determinants further? Prefer general method for similar matrices

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best method out there, but for the denominator, you could do this:

$$
\begin{vmatrix} \binom{1}{0}  &  \binom{1}{1} & 0& 0\\ 
\binom{2}{0} &  \binom{2}{1} & \binom{2}{2} & 0\\
\binom{3}{0}  &  \binom{3}{1}& \binom{3}{2}&  \binom{3}{3}  \\ 
\binom{4}{0}  &  \binom{4}{1} & \binom{4}{2} &  \binom{4}{3}\end{vmatrix}\\[8ex]
= \begin{vmatrix} 1  &  1 & 0& 0\\ 
1 &  2 & 1 & 0\\
1 &  3& 3&  1  \\ 
1  &  4 & 6 &  4\end{vmatrix} \;\;\;\;\; \text{(Simplifying the binomial coeffs.)}\\ 
=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & 6 & 4
\end{vmatrix}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ \ \  \text{($\mathrm{C}_2 \to \mathrm{C}_2-\mathrm{C}_1$)} \\[2ex]
=1\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 3 &1\\
3 & 6 & 4
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 1 &1\\
3 & 3 & 4
\end{vmatrix}
=1
$$

---

Now for the numerator:

$$\begin{vmatrix} 
a&  \binom{1}{1}  & 0& 0\\ 
b &  \binom{2}{1} & \binom{2}{2} & 0\\
c &  \binom{3}{1} & \binom{3}{2} &  \binom{3}{3}  \\ 
d &  \binom{4}{1} & \binom{4}{2}&  \binom{4}{3} \end{vmatrix}
\\[8ex] 
=\begin{vmatrix} 
a&  1  & 0& 0\\ 
b &  2 & 1 & 0\\
c &  3 & 3 & 1 \\ 
d &  4 & 6 & 4 
\end{vmatrix}
\\[4ex]
=\begin{vmatrix}
a & 1 & 0 & 0\\
b & 2 & 1 & 0\\
c & 3 & 0 & 1\\
d & 4 & -6& 4\\ 
\end{vmatrix} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{($\mathrm{C_3}\to\mathrm{C_3}-3\mathrm{C}_4$)}\\[8ex]
=a
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 1\\
4 & -6& 4\\
\end{vmatrix}
-
\begin{vmatrix}
b & 1 & 0\\
c & 0 & 1\\
d &-6 & 4\\
\end{vmatrix}\\[8ex]
=4a-6b+4c-d
$$
Finally, we have :
$$\boxed{q=4a-6b+4c-d}$$

Comment: sign error at last step

Comment: It would probably be $4a-6b+4c-d$.

Comment: @Buraian fixed. Thanks for pointing out